# Java String formatting Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, loops, formatting

I am new to Regex and Java String formatting and I would like to format this string:

```
String text = "[(0 : 1 : 0), (2 : 11 : 1), (2 : 12 : 1)]";
```

The numbers are point coordinates x,y,z and I want to be able to assign values inside the brackets to objects - so I need to isolate them, then get only the number value. Could anyone help me with what regex can help me achieve that? I list some specifications of my problem.

- The number of points in the text value will vary greatly - it can be 0 to n.
- I want to be able to iterate over the string to assign each coordinate correctly (x,y,z) so I need the brackets () which indicate end and start of point and : which indicate end and start of a coordinate.

I am looking for a pattern which would help me achieve this - I looked up classes like format, Pattern, and so on and methods like replaceAll but I am really stuck on what pattern to use to be able to iterate in a way it recognizes the coordinate correctly - you can see that a coordinate can be double digit so it must take all the numbers which follow after the :.

Comment: any particular reason why you want a regex for that?

Comment: Is that `:0` with no space between in the first tuple, or is there always space before and after colon?

Comment: It’s not too bad. You need a regex that matches `(0 : 1 :0)` where each number is, say, 1 through 8 digits (with an optional minus sign?). And you need capturing groups for the numbers — use round brackets. Then you need to call `Matcher.find()` repeatedly to match each tuple. For each tuple found take out the captured groups and parse them to `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: @Ole V.V. - I am sorry that was a typo - there is always space after and before :

njzk2 - I just thought it would do the job for me - do you have a better solution without regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this acheives what you want:

```
    String text = "[(0 : 1 :0), (2 : 11 : 1), (2 : 12 : 1)]";
    String patternString = "\\((\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2) + " " + matcher.group(3));
    }
```

I don't know about elegant but some explanations for the future. Regexp originally looks like this: `\((\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\)` because it's java we need to escape slash by adding extra slash, so all single slashes become double slashes . ' \( ' and ' \)' mean find literally a bracket. Then we use (\d+) to find at least one number and capture it to capture group. \D+ - find at least one nonNumber. Helpful resources for dealing with regexp for the future: regex101.com regexone.com tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed !!! Thank you for such a fast response and elegant solution!!

Comment: It’s a very good start. It doesn’t seem to fulfil *get only the number value*, but maybe the OP can handle that. For better validation I’d use `\s+:\s+` rather than `\D+` between the numbers, but I admit that it’s pretension.

Comment: I don't know about elegant but some explanations for the future.

Regexp originally looks like this:
```\((\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\)```

because it's java we need to escape slash by adding extra slash, so all single slashes become double slashes . ' \( ' and ' \)' mean find literally a bracket. Then we use (\d+) to find at least one number and capture it to capture group. \D+ - find at least one nonNumber.

Helpful resources for dealing with regexp for the future:

https://regex101.com/
https://regexone.com/
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Please accept answer.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks! Comments are not always persistent on Stack Overflow, and also not all users read them, so anything for the future should go into the answer itself. I pasted your good explanation in there for you.